# Can Alpha Decays and Gamma Decays be expressed via Feynman Diagrams?

Tags: nuclear-physics, feynman-diagrams, radiation

I just learnt about Feynman Diagrams, and I've been going through many examples to practice the reading of Feynman Diagrams myself. I have already found diagrams for Positron Emission, Electron Capture, and Beta Emission decays but yet have not seen one on Alpha emission or Gamma decays.

Can these decay mechanisms be expressed through Feynman diagrams, or am I just missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw a diagram, but it's probably not a Feynman diagram. They represent formal terms in a perturbation theory expansion of a scattering amplitude in a relativistic quantum field theory.

Meanwhile, alpha and gamma decays are more decay amplitudes a la Fermi's Golden Rule. So in gamma decays, you have an excited state nucleus and (usually) a ground state of the same nucleus, then you compute the matrix element connecting them (e.g., a dipole operator).

Alpha decay is covered by Gamow theory, which is an approximate solution to tunneling probably via the Schrödinger Equation (maybe with some relativistic kinematics corrections).

So basically, alpha and beta decay are well described by quantum mechanics, and quantum field theory is not necessary. (But that doesn't mean someone hasn't tried it).

Comment: Is QFT a field within QM, or does QM refer to non-field theory (pre-Dirac basically)? From a terminology standpoint